# Why does my remote desktop session introduce custom scaling and blurry text

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, fonts

I have noticed this problem for a few years now. It happens primarily when I use Remote Desktop Connection from Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro connecting to my Windows 10 Desktop but I have also had it happen connecting from my Windows 10 Desktop to another Windows 10 Desktop.

Essentially, the remote machine will have fuzzy text and some websites are practically unreadable. I think it may be Windows applying custom scaling as sometimes if I have access to my desktop I can turn off custom scaling, log out and back in and it is resolved for a short while. This is not an option through Remote Desktop Connection. I have also tried messing with the RDC settings, "Font Smoothing enabled" etc. but does not seem to work.

I should note that it does occasionally happen on the actual host machine so I'm not sure if it's anything to do with RDC, it just seems to show up more then.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems unlikely that your machine could go for a few years without doing driver and windows updates. Look at Windows RDC, more options, display and set display options, especially color depth, for best presentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer that you are connecting from (MAC) updates the resolution of the remote computer (Windows 7) then the DPI will change on the remote computer. For everything to adjust to the new DPI after initiating the remote connection you must logout.

To fix this issue maybe connect to the Windows Computer and change the settings on the RDP Client to keep the source resolution of the remote computer that way the DPI will not update or change the resolution of the Windows Computer to match the Mac you are connecting from.

Answer (score 0):

I set "Graphics interpolation level" to "None" in my MacOS Microsoft Remote Client preferences which fixed the blurry text after a logout / login of the RDP session.